# How to disable "bundle check" in circleci config/yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, circleci

I use a private gem in an application, which is located at a private gem server.
There is no access to that gem server outside of VPC.
In my `Gemfile` I put the private gem inside a custom group:

```
group :private do
  source 'http://private-server-address' do
    gem 'private-gem'
  end
end
```

I added these lines into `circle.yml` file to tell cicleci bundler to ignore my private gem:

```
dependencies:
  bundler:
    without: [production, staging, private]
```

But the problem is circleci runs `bundle check` and right after that just `bundle install` without any options.

Is it possible to disable `bundle check`? I couldn't find any info in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to disable `bundle check`. I ended up using this workaround. Circleci sets some environment variables, so we can use them to tell bundler to ignore certain gems:

```
if !ENV['CIRCLECI']
  source 'http://your-private-address' do
    gem 'your_private_gem'
  end
end
```

And we don't need `group :private` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `bundle config without` followed by a list of groups that you wish to exclude, e.g.:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - bundle config without development:production
```

This would ignore the 'development' and 'production' groups.